# UnboundLocalError: when calling function output

Tags: python

I want to convert a list of values from 0, 1 and 2 to 2,2; 1,2 and 1,1. I wrote a function which is supposed to be doing that:

```
def dec2(code):                      
    if code == 0:
        ret_val = '2','2'
    elif code == 1:
         ret_val = '1','2'
    elif code == 2:
         ret_val = '1','1'
    else:
        ret_val = '0','0'
    return ret_val
```

It seems to be working fine as long as I run it on ready made lists:

```
In [87]: a=[1,2,1,2]

In [88]: b=[dec2(x) for x in a]

In [89]: b
Out[89]: [('1', '2'), ('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('1', '1')]
```

However, when I try to use it to substitute dictionary values, I get UnboundLocalError.:

```
In [82]: gtps
Out[82]: {11: [1, 2, 1, 2], 22: [2, 2, 1, 1], 33: [1, 9, 0, 2]}
[86]: for k,v in gtps.iteritems():
....:     tmp=[dec2(x) for x in v]
....:     all[k]=tmp
....:
....:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ret_val' referenced before assignment
```

ANy ideas?

Comment: The code you showed us won't raise an `UnboundLocalError`; make sure you are working with the *right* `dec2()` function version. And why not just return early from `dec2()`, or better yet, use a mapping?

Comment: I just wrote this function, so there are no versions to speak of... I'm afraid I'm not very faimiliar with mapping!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted cannot under any circumstances raise `UnboundLocalError`, so you have something mixed up in your ipython session there.

I'd use this instead:

```
_code_map = {0: ('2', '2'), 1: ('1','2'), 2: ('1','1')}
def dec2(code):
    return _code_map.get(code, ('0', '0'))
```

Comment: I have run the original code through a script and indeed, it looks like my code is ok. Any idea what is wrong with my ipython?

Comment: @branwen85: I guess you have a previous version still loaded that you didn't complete editing. Or perhaps you accidentally named a newer revision with a typo.